# SvelteKit with TypeScript - Handling Events

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

```
<script lang="ts">
    let expression = '0';

    function handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        let value = (event.currentTarget as HTMLElement).textContent
        if (expression === '0') {
            (expression = value);
        } else {
            (expression += expression);
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="calc">
        <input type="text" class="calc__display" bind:value={expression} />
        <div class="calc__buttons">
            <button on:click={handleClick}>8</button>
            <button on:click={handleClick}>7</button>
            <button on:click={handleClick}>9</button>
            <button on:click={handleClick}>&divide</button>
        </div>
<!-- the rest of the buttons -->
```

`(expression = value);` - this line of code is giving me an error: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

So when a user click to one of the buttons, it will trigger the function handleClick().
The said function will be responsible for updating the content .calc__display.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error state, `textContent` can be `null` and thus not assigned to a non-nullable type.

You could either e.g. add a guard expression that checks for that case or, since you know that it will be defined add [a non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) by adding `!` at the end.

This is not idiomatic anyway though. You can just send the parameter directly to the function instead of querying/reading the DOM, which should be avoided.

e.g.

```js
// ...
const expressions = ['8', '7', '9', '&divide'];

function onExpressionClick(ex: string) {
    if (expression === '0') {
        expression = ex;
    } else {
        // This just copies the expression, is that intended?
        expression += expression;
    }
}
```

replace buttons with:

```html
{#each expressions as ex}
  <button on:click={() => onExpressionClick(ex)}>{ex}</button>
{/each}
```